# How to apply background to specific elements only?

Tags: html, css

Is there an elegant, some kind of an easy way to switch the circle's background with the div's background under them?

I want the circles to apply the div "one" image background, but the div "one" to be invisible(not the visibility:hidden ofc).

I don't need to hardcore the heck out of it, I want an elegant/sort of an easy way to make this.

IE10/11 support and above.

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://ak5.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/11223065/thumb/1.jpg");
}

.two,
.three {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  left: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.three {
  left: initial;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want a hole ? to see behind ?

Comment: Thanks Temani Afif for making it more accessible

Comment: Yeah, kinda a hole. "transparent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy CSS solution for this but you can use SVG:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red)
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="300">
  <defs>
    <!-- define the mask-->
    <mask id="hole">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <!-- the first hole -->
      <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="150" fill="black"/>
      <!-- the second hole -->
      <circle r="50" cx="400" cy="150" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
    <!-- define the background image -->
  <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="500" height="300">
    <image  xlink:href="https://ak5.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/11223065/thumb/1.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" />
  </pattern>
  </defs>
  <!-- create a rect, fill it with the image and apply the above mask -->
  <rect fill="url(#img)" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#hole)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: OMG! I never used svg before, maaaaan... it's awesome!  did you just write it like this or do you use some tool for this? I'm just wowed man. for real

Comment: @wazay well i just wrote it ;) but I already have some knwoledge about SVG and I did similar thing before ... and you will see that it's not too hard, simply google each element I used in the SVG and you will understand how it works ;)