# Is it possible to make a hole in an img element using html/javascript/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a website from which the background partly needs to be transparant because a video behind it needs to come through. The background is an image. Also, I need to make sure that the website runs on Opera version 11.

Is there a way to cute a hole in an image element, taking into account that the website needs to run in an Opera 11 browser? 
 `<img src='http://ip/cutaholeinme.png'>`

So that in the end, the following `image with a hole` is displayed; (the white rectangle should be transparent)

[image]

Comment: Why not have a `png` image with the hole already in it?

Comment: Use GIMP, mark that rectangle using "R" and mouse, and press Delete. Save as PNG. Done.

Comment: And btw, you don't use `url`in `<img src=url('http://ip/cutaholeinme.png')>`, instead simply go `<img src=http://ip/cutaholeinme.png>`

Comment: @connexo  You might want to put some quotes on that too.. :)

Comment: @Keith Quotes are not required. For attribute values, it is perfectly legal to use double quotes, single quotes, and, as long as the attribute value doesn't contain a space character, omit the quotes.

Comment: @Roy I wanted to know if there is a different option which does not need the image to be edited.

Comment: @Klyner No, there is none. But why not simply place the element you want to "shine through" on top of the image?

Comment: @connexo That was the initial idea, but I am developing for a specific deprecated settopbox which does not support this. :( > https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=120156

Comment: @Klyner I don't believe it doesn't support this. That would mean it doesn't support `position: absolute;`. What browser should that be? Lynx?

Comment: Try use `clip-path:` CSS property

Comment: @connexo I am using the corresponding settopbox library to display a video with, instead of doing this in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

A `mask` can easily do this

```css
img {
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top   / 100% 50px, /* show 50px from the top */
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom/ 100% 70px, /* show 70px from the bottom */
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left  / 20% 100%,  /* show 20% from the left */
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right / 40% 100%;  /* show 40% from the right */
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top   / 100% 50px,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom/ 100% 70px,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left  / 20px 100%,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right / 40px 100%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,blue,red);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1006/500/400" >
```

For better support, you can consider an SVG mask: [How to apply background to specific elements only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49967736/8620333)

---

You can also consider a trick with multiple elements like below:

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 0 0;
}

.box div {
  background: inherit;
  height: 100%;
}

.box:before,
.box:after,
.box div:before,
.box div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: 500px 400px;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  background-position:top;
  height: 20%;
}

.box:after {
  bottom: 0;
  background-position:bottom;
  height: 30%;
}

.box div:before,
.box div:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.box div:before {
  left: 0;
  background-position:left;
  width: 40px;
}

.box div:after {
  right: 0;
  background-position:right;
  width: 80px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1006/500/400)">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly `mask` is not supported by Opera version 11. https://caniuse.com/#search=mask

Comment: use the SVG version

Comment: Unfortunatelly even `background-position` is not supported in Opera v11.